# Check if file is actually a zipfile

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I know I can use `testzip` or just try to uncompress the file and catch the exception.

My issue is that I might have `.msg` files which have attachments that are zipfiles.

In that case the `ZipFile` will just skip over the first few bytes, open the attached zip file and not raise an exception.

The only way I can come up with this is manually opening the file and check the first two bytes to see if it's `PK`, but I'd just like to have a more "strict" check.

Is this possible with either `ZipFile` or another library?

Comment: Just an idea: maybe running `file` command through `subprocess` and checking the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is "actually a zipfile" for you?

A file marked as such with `PK`?
A valid "header" at the end of the file?

There are files in the wild that work as PE executable, ZIP, and PDF at the same time.
The most strict you can get would probably both the PK and reading the header. You already answered your own question.

Comment: I ended up checking the first four bytes (`80`, `75`, `3`, `4`), because apparently there's no way to make some sort of strict check. Even the command line `unzip` tool will just discard the first few bytes, print a warning and extract anyway.